# GeoServer with viewparams returns ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: geoserver

I am trying to call a JSON request from geoserver which has an Oracle NG Layer.  I have one parameter in the call:

```
viewparams=customer:One Customer
```

The parameter value has to have a space in it.  I cannot get it to work, and am getting the following error:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd"><ServiceException>
      java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException
java.io.IOException
null
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

This is the url:

```
http://pc121212:8085/geoserver/sf/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=sf:view_ae&viewparams=customer:One%20Customer&outputFormat=JSON
```

When I go into "Edit SQL View" for the layer in GeoServer, this is the query:

```
select * from view_ae
where customer = %customer%
```

The parameter in GeoServer is added with the following values:

```
Name = customer
Default value = 'One Customer'
Valid Regular Expression = ^[\w\d\s]+$
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: At least, because it is a string, I believe that you should use `where customer = '%customer%'`

Comment: It will not work with the single quotes.  If you try that in GeoServer "Edit Sql view", when you go to save the query, it gives you an error right away.

Comment: How about using "ilike" as in the document page http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html? But I noticed only now that you are using Oracle. That may not be so well tested.

Comment: Correct, I am using Oracle, ilike does not exist there.

Comment: Raise GeoServer logging to GeoToos developer or Verbose and try to capture the SQL that gets sent to Oracle when the error happens.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed after tip by @user30184 to look at the logs!

VERY IMPORTANT: Do not put quotes around the default value on your parameter in the "Sql view paremeters" section.

These are the two changes required:

1. Place single quotes around the parameter in the "Sql Statement" section:

   select * from view_ae
   where customer = '%customer%'
2. In the "Sql view paremeters" section, On your Sql view parameter, DO NOT include single quotes around the Default Value, if not you will get an error as mentioned in my comments above.  This is how it should look:

   Default value = One Customer

Once you do those two changes, the issue is resolved.  Hope someone finds this post useful.